# Enable/Disable custom ribbon commands not working in OfficeJS Excel

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

We have implemented Enable/Disable feature in Excel add-in and below are the findings.

1. Initially we were able to disable the custom ribbon commands in manifest file.
2. Once logged into excel we were able to enable the required disabled commands.
3. But if we again trying to click login command the page(taskpane.ts) is not getting refreshed.
4. We are using single task-pane and It is implemented required shared runtime as "long".

**Expected behavior**

1. How to reload the task-pane once logged into the application in shared runtime.
2. How to get button id of the **ShowTaskPane** from manifest file.

If we got solution for above expected behavior it can be achieved enable/disable easily in our application.

Comment: Hi Team, I could able to get command event id in taskpane using ExecuteFunction from manifest file. But still could not achieving refreshing taskpane...... Kindly help ASAP.

Comment: Hi Team...can i have update/help on this?